# how to remove one row from small code

Tags: php

I have a php code.

```
$count_news_of_category = '';
while($row = $db->get_row($sql_result))
{ 
if( $row['new_'] == '0') {$news_now = ')';} else {$news_now = '/+'.$row['new_'].')';};
$t = '('.$row['allnews_'].$news_now;
$tpl->set('{count_categ_'.$row['id'].'}', $t); 
$count_news_of_category .= $row['id'].'#'.$t.'|';
}
```

output is such: [image]
It show number of all news from category and number of today's news from that category.

I want to remove () and /+1

Need help. I am a newbie and don't know anything. can you remove it and write here code? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the reference to `$news_now`, looks like that's what's adding the +1, also remove the `'('.` from in front of `$row['allnews_']`

```
$count_news_of_category = '';
while($row = $db->get_row($sql_result))
{ 
    $t = $row['allnews_'];
    $tpl->set('{count_categ_'.$row['id'].'}', $t); 
    $count_news_of_category .= $row['id'].'#'.$t.'|';
}
```

Comment: +1 cause you got it 5 seconds before me and it's identical ;)

Comment: wow thanks a lot. it works. I cant give you +1, i have no reputation. but I thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
$count_news_of_category = '';
while($row = $db->get_row($sql_result))
{ 
  $t = $row['allnews_'].$news_now;
  $tpl->set('{count_categ_'.$row['id'].'}', $t); 
  $count_news_of_category .= $row['id'].'#'.$t.'|';
}
```